# Subtract Difference Between Current Week and Prior Week Data Load

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

Every **week** I download a new file of data that contains Group and Year information. I need to compare Current Week (CW) values with Prior Week (PW) values to understand changes in the data. How can that calculation be done in DAX?

**Data:**

| CW/PW | Group | Year | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CW | 1 | 2020 | 10 |
| CW | 1 | 2021 | 8 |
| CW | 2 | 2020 | 5 |
| CW | 2 | 2021 | 15 |
| CW | 3 | 2020 | 12 |
| CW | 3 | 2021 | 8 |
| PW | 1 | 2020 | 9 |
| PW | 1 | 2021 | 10 |
| PW | 2 | 2020 | 4 |
| PW | 2 | 2021 | 13 |
| PW | 3 | 2020 | 7 |
| PW | 3 | 2021 | 8 |

**Result:**

| * | Group | 2020 | 2021 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CW | 1 | 10 | 8 |
| PW | 1 | 9 | 10 |
| **Delta** | **1** | **1** | **-2** |
| CW | 2 | 5 | 15 |
| PW | 2 | 4 | 13 |
| **Delta** | **2** | **1** | **2** |
| CW | 3 | 12 | 8 |
| PW | 3 | 7 | 8 |
| **Delta** | **3** | **5** | **0** |

Comment: Doesn't 15 belong to Group 2?

Comment: @jprzd Just fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's already answered but this is an alternative

[image]

Answer (score 2):

First you can create a new Table. Click new table and put in the following:

```
Tabel = SUMMARIZE(Blad1, Blad1[Year], Blad1[Group], "CW", CALCULATE(SUM(Blad1[Value]), Blad1[CW/PW] = "CW"), "PW",  CALCULATE(SUM(Blad1[Value]), Blad1[CW/PW] = "PW"))
```

Blad1 is your Sheet name you gave it with the import. It summarizes by year and group and adds 2 columns with the values of CW and PW.

Next you can add a column:

```
Delta = Tabel[CW]-Tabel[PW]
```

This is obvious, it calculates the difference..